# Printing a node in a linked list

Tags: python, linked-list, repr

I'm very new to coding and I have a basic question about printing a node in a doubly linked list in Python.

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, key = None, prev = None, next = None):
        self.key = key
        self.prev = prev
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        return ('[%s][%d][%s]' % (repr(self.prev), self.key, repr(self.next)))
```

Obviously I then have some more code for the list class itself.  Let's say I have a doubly linked list with two nodes:

> **node1**: key 21
>   **node2**: key 10
>   head --> node1 <==> node2

If I do print(node1) I get:

```
[*location of prev node*][21][*location of next node*]
```

which works exactly how I want.

So 2 questions:

1. Is this code "messy" or acceptable syntax for the str method?
2. Instead of printing the *location* of the prev and next nodes, how would I print the *names* of the nodes instead e.g. `[node7][82][node9]`?

Hope this makes sense, and thanks for any help!

Comment: 1. That's fine.  2. Your nodes don't have names.  If you want them to have names then you'd have to have some `self.name` attribute.  One of the properties of a linked list is that the individual noes don't know where in the list they are, only their neighbors.

Comment: *names of the nodes* - at least, each Node instance should have `name` attribute

Comment: @PatrickHaugh thanks for your reply.  OK so once I've made a node, it doesn't know its own name...I'd have to set up a self.name attribute like you said...got it!  I'm guessing its not common practice to do this though since its not really necessary to print nodes out in a pretty format.

Comment: Usually you just refer to nodes by their contents.  In most scenarios, the node object would hold a key that is a reference (i.e. pointer) to something else in memory. So the node that pointed to memory location `0xdeadbeef` would be `node 0xdeadbeef`

Comment: If your list has cycles, your `repr` will stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having to create a `self.name` needed to be initialized for each `Node`. You could add a `self.id` initialized with a static `counter` incremented at each creation.

**Step 1** - add a static `counter` and initialize the `self.id` attribute

The `counter`starts from `0` and is accessible through `Node.counter`.

```
class Node():
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self, key = None, prev = None, next = None):
        Node.counter += 1
        self.id = Node.counter
        self.key = key
        self.prev = prev
        self.next = next
```

**Step 2** - modify the `__str__` function to get the `id` of `prev` and `next`

The name of the `self.prev` and `self.next` is only displayed when not
`None`.

Recover the name of the class with `self.__class__.__name__`.

```
def __str__(self):
    sprev = repr(self.prev)
    if self.prev != None :
        sprev = '%s%d' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.prev.id)
    snext = repr(self.next)
    if self.next != None :
        snext = '%s%d' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.next.id)
    return ('[%s][%d][%s]' % (sprev, self.key, snext))
```

Here are some examples:

```
>>> node1 = Node(21)
>>> print(node1)
[None][21][None]
>>> node2 = Node(10,node1)
>>> print(node2)
[Node1][10][None]
>>> node3 = Node(11,node2,node1)
>>> print(node3)
[Node2][11][Node1]
```